# BigQuery public datasets cannot be found (`bigquery-public-data`)

Tags: google-bigquery

In the left panel of BigQuery, the dataset `bigquery-public-data` is nowhere to be found.

I have no idea how it disappeared. Does anyone have a solution to integrate it back?

Comment: Are you looking on the new UI or old? I can see them on the old version but not on the new

Comment: I am talking about the old UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old (Classic) UI, you can pin the project back by following the steps in the "Adding a project" section of this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-classic-ui#adding_and_removing_projects). There is a screenshot in the link.

I'm not sure how it disappeared from your Console, but there is a "Remove project from panel" option in the down arrow icon next to each pinned project.

Answer (score 7):

I am currently enrolled in the Google Data Analytics course and just found where an instructor told us how to pin the bigquery-public-data to the explorer!

In the search bar of your explorer, type "public" and then select the broaden search in blue. This should populate the bigquery-data-public so that you are able to pin it to your explorer.

I have spent two days trying to figure this out so I hope this reaches someone in need!

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why is it so tough to add public datasets. The official documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/query-public-dataset-console#open_a_public_dataset tells you to search for 'bigquery-public-data' but this returns 0 results, and just searching for 'public' like you said here and starring the project, works as intended!